# Сложности установки конфигурации NvChad для nvim

Tags: ide, vim

Всем привет. Пытаюсь установить конфигурацию NvChad как в [документации](https://nvchad.com/docs/quickstart/install), но получаю лишь непонятный зеленый экран с непонятными стилями оформления нижней панели. Почему так происходит?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]